# How can I add nodes and edges to existing echarts Graph (in React)?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I'm trying to update an existing Graph (`type: "graph"`) I built with `echarts-for-react` but I couldn't find a way to do it. I see in ECharts API documentation [appendData](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.appendData) function but I can't make it work.

I tried to following code:

```js
  chart.getEchartsInstance().appendData({
    seriesIndex: 0,
    data: props.nodes,
    links: props.edges,
    categories: props.categories
  })
```

But I don't see any effect on Graph.

Comment: The `appendData` function has some limitations (under Notice in [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.appendData)) whcih may or may not apply to your case. The standard way to update a chart is through [`setOption`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption)

Comment: I couldn't make it work at all the docs are pretty limited.

Comment: Then post your code so we can help.